# Return a char array with any length in C?

Tags: arrays, c, return-value

How do I return a char array with any length in C?

```
char string[](int, int);
```

doesn't work; is there a way to return a char array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to do that in C.
Instead, return a pointer.

```
char *string(int length, int unused) {
  char *s = calloc(x, sizeof(char));
  return s;
}
```

Comment: How can I use this pointer?

Comment: Calling `calloc()` without clearing the allocated memory with `free()` will lead to memory leakage.

Comment: @jonasPamm You use this pointer just like you would use a normal string allocated on the stack: `char *str = string(10, 0);  strncpy(str, "hello", 10); str[9] = 0;`